# Security in a Word with password

Tags: microsoft-word, security

How secure is a word document if I put a password to open it?
I suppose is more save to put information in a note of Apple Keychain or 1Password, is that correct?

Comment: I cannot say for sure, but if you really want to secure data, crypt your file with some real crypto-tool. I'd recommend using PGP/GnuPG there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_password_protection:

> Currently, the 40-bit key protection used in Office 97–2003 can be
>   easily cracked by the password-hacking software. The 128-bit key AES
>   protection employed in Office 2007–2010 can still be considered as a
>   relatively secure one. At the moment, however, cloud computing
>   facilities are capable of unlocking a substantial number of the files
>   saved in the Office 2007–2010 format.

Considering that, if you want your data to be really secure, use a third-party product to encrypt the document.